# File is getting saved in UTF16 format. What might be the issue?

Tags: c#

I am trying to save xml string as file, file is getting saved in UTF16 format. What might be the issue?

```
private void SaveFile(string xmlData, string fileName)
{
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, xmlData, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Even though I have mentioned Encoding as UTF8 still the file is getting saved in UTF16 format.

Comment: How are you serializing the xmlData string?

Comment: are you sure you are talking about the Fileformat of the file - and not the header in the XML ?

Comment: How have you verified the file format?

Comment: The `File.WriteAllText()` method is known to work correctly. You specify `Encoding.UTF8` and this will be respected.

The only plausible explanations for what you describe are that:

1. You have double encoded the text when creating `xmlData`.
2. The UTF-16 that you report is that written in the XML header.
The bottom line is that the error is to be found in code that cannot be seen in the question.

Comment: To add to Cadburry's comment, the XML string you're trying to save may contain `encoding="utf-16"`, but that doesn't mean the file is in that format.

Comment: If you open the file in notepad, and choose 'save as', what appears in the encoding dropdown?

Comment: better to add concise format of your xml by seeing your header xml we can determine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have done something like:

```
string xml;
using(var sw = new StringWriter()) {
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, obj);
    xml = sw.ToString();
}
```

in which case yes, the xml will internally declare utf-16, because it has correctly determined that *it is writing to something that is inherently utf-16*. There are probably ways to work around this in the writer (`XmlWriterSettings.Encoding`, for example), but a better approach would be either:

- to write/serialize directly to the file, for example via a `StreamWriter` onto the file
- to write/serialize to a `MemoryStream` rather than a `StringWriter`, since `MemoryStream` has no inherent utf-16 encoding

The encoding of a *file* is not quite the same thing as the declared encoding in the xml; if the xml **as a string** says utf-16, that won't magically change just because you write the string as utf-8